# Prevent enter firing button click in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to sort out a user interface problem where an enter key pressed in an input field is effectively firing a click event on a button (presumably because it now has the focus). The button in question has a prevent modifier on its click action (i.e., `<button @click.prevent="blah">`), but that doesn't help. What I want to do is ensure that the button action is only executed by an actual click on the button, not by enter in a preceding input field.

LATER: I have this working now using `<a @click.prevent="blah">` instead, with the link styled as a button via Bootstrap. This doesn't have the problem - an Enter key doesn't fire the handler. It seems **insane** to me that there is no way of distinguishing between a mouse click on a button and the Enter key firing it. Both are seen as a MouseEvent, and I can find no way of differentiating between the two.

Comment: In your event handler, have you tried `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Isn't that what `@click.prevent` does for me?

Answer (score 15):

Actually, the answer was extraordinarily simple, but not immediately obvious. I was using plain `<button>`. I had forgotten to add what the type tag, which I normally would, thus: `<button type="button">` Once this was in place, the Enter key no longer fired it.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe this was it. This had been killing me for so long! Thank you so much. I have never come across this before.

Comment: Same here, days looking for the answer!! thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

What worked best for me was an empty `@click.prevent=""` in combination with `@mousedown.prevent="myfunction"`.

This:

- prevents the 'Enter' key from triggering a click
- keeps the tag from receiving focus on click (except on keyboard navigation)
- prevents page reload on any `href="#"`

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j8fchbvk/37/

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I fixed it by getting rid of the `<form>` tag . Since Vuex was handling form-submission, I did not need the form tag anyhow.